# How can I use Google Chrome inspect network to know how to increase my website performance?

Tags: javascript, css, performance, google-chrome, web-inspector

My web application is slow I don't know why, but I think CSS and JS files is the reason. I use PHP with Firebase and it takes too long as you can see in image.

How I can increase performance of my website? I tried to use `inspect-> network` to see how much time every file takes to execute on my web application and I see that the problem in CSS and JS, but I don't know how to fix it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you use a bad algorithm to do your job or garbage code you need to check js files how it work and use modern js code instead of nested loop of nested if statement all of that maybe one of reason why your website is slow